# Exposing state of array in a closure without allowing it to be edited from the outside

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, closures

I'm working on a simple Tic Tac Toe game where I have a revealing module representing the playing field and containing the playing logic without any knowledge of the DOM:

```
var gameBoard = function() {

    var createBackingArray = function(size) {
        var f = new Array(size);
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            f[i] = new Array(size);
        }
        return f;
    };

    var field = createBackingArray(3);

    var getField = function(){
        //Return a copy of the array to prevent the field 
        //from being manipulated from firebug, etc.
        return field.slice(0); 
    }

    var isFreeToPlay = function(x, y) { //stuff };

    var playField = function(x, y, player) { //stuff };

    return {
        getField: getField,
        isFreeToPlay: isFreeToPlay,
        playField: playField
    };

}();
```

and in another script I have all the DOM-related stuff, e.g.

```
var createDomField = function(fieldData) {
    var table = $("<table/>");

    var length = fieldData.length;
    for (var row = 0; row < length; row++) {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        for (var cell = 0; cell < length; cell++) {
            var newCell = $("<td>");
            newCell.html(fieldData[row][cell]);
            newRow.append(newCell);
        }
        table.append(newRow);
    }
    return table;
};

var updateField = function(){
    var field = createDomField(gameBoard.getField());
    elem.fieldContainer.empty();
    elem.fieldContainer.append(field)
}
```

When creating a copy of the array, like above, every time I update/redraw the field will I be causing memory leaks (e.g. if I call updateField a gazillion times) or will duplicated array be garbage collected when the function completes and the DOM has been updated?

If it's not GC-ed is there a way to manually clean it up somehow?

is this a bad/ugly way of doing this?
is there a better way to expose the state of the array and still have it "private" in the closure so it cannot be manipulated with dev tools/firebug?

Comment: ... are you trying to prevent the client, who runs all your JavaScript in the first place, from accessing part of the JavaScript heap, which is part of the clients' RAM and managed by the JavaScript VM running on the client?

Comment: ergh.. yes? Honestly, I think you lost me..

Comment: What I'm saying is you can't prevent your JS data from being manipulated with dev tools/firebug and should do something more productive with your time. No matter what you do, your code runs on the client and your data is stored on the client. The client can do with it whatever it wants. That's not to say there aren't other reasons to not expose everything (there are - encapsulation is good design).

Comment: In the way it works now (returning a copy of the array), doesn't that at least somewhat protected the original array from manipulation from other scripts/firebug? Or where you thinking of more hardcore ways of manipulation, like accessing the memory or something? 
(not trying to argue, just curious)

I'm doing this just for fun and to learn JS a bit better, so I think trying to accomplish this as at least somewhat productive (for me) =)

Comment: Firebug: It's pretty trivial to just put a breakpoint in one of your "privileged" functions and play around with the internal variable. Other JS files: Dunno, probably much harder, but I wouldn't assume anything.

Comment: ooh, good point about the breakpoint (no pun intended), I've never thought of that =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to make `createBackingArray` public, and instead of `getField` you could have `populateField`.   `updateField` would **re-use its own instance of array** that it created with `createBackingArray` and just re-fetch data with `populateField`.

Here's an example:  http://pastie.org/8266775

Comment: Could you elaborate, perhaps with a short little snippet of example code?

Comment: I added a link to an example.